# Built-in function to get column at point

Tags: column

Is there a built-in function that does this:

```el
(defun mk-column-at (point)
  "Return column number at POINT."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char point)
    (current-column)))
```

Comment: No, there is not to my knowledge -- but such an invention at the c-source-code level sure would be nice.

Comment: For an alternative approach when point is visible, have a look at the code for the function `line-move-visual` in `simple.el`.  The presence of certain overlays (e.g., with the after-string property), however, conflict with that approach when point is at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

1. "*Point*" means something in Emacs. It is the buffer position just before the text cursor - the position at which text is self-inserted. It is confusing to name a parameter `POINT`, since point typically does not correspond to whatever position might be passed to the function as argument. Better to call it `POSITION` or `POS` or `POSN`, following convention, or something else.
2. Wrt the question, there is no such predefined function, as far as I know. What you write is about as succinct as it gets.  I would probably just use the code in the function body, rather than bothering to define a function for this, but what you've done seems reasonable to me.